# How to query multiple tables in mysql using java and using where

Tags: java, mysql

I have a database with 15 tables I am trying to extract data from 6 of those tables.

Here are my tables:

doginfo (Table name)

DogId int Auto_increment PRimary

regnum varchar(20) not null

RegName varchar(50)

WhelpDate varchar(10) not null

OwnerId int not null

CoOwnerId int

SireId int not null

DamId int not null

ArrivalDate varchar(10) not null

DepartureDate varchar(10)

CallName int not null

DNA char(3) not null

Notes text not null

---

dogat (Table name)

AtId int not null auto_increment Primary

Sex varchar(6) not null

Breed varChar(25)

Color Varchar(20) not null

DogId int not null

---

sires (Table name)

SireId int not null auto_increment Primary

SireRegName varchar(50) not null

SireRegNum int

DogId int not null

---

Dams (Table name)

DamId int not null auto_increment Primary

DamRegName varchar(50) not null

DamRegNum int

DogId int not null

---

owners (Table name)

OwnerId int not null auto_increment Primary

FirstName varchar(50) not null

MiddleName varchar(50)

LastName varchar(50) not null

Address1 varchar(75) not null

Address2 varchar(75)

City varchar(75) not null

State char(2) not null

Zip varchar(10) not null

HTel varchar(13)

Cell varchar(13)

WTel varchar(13)

email varchar(150)

Occupation varchar(50)

CreditCardNum varchar(25)

CCExperation varchar(10)

SpouseId int

DogId int not null

---

coowneres (Table name)

CoOwnerId int not null auto_increment Primary

CoOwnerNames varchar(150)

City varchar(75 not null

State char(2) not null

Zip varchar(10) not null

DogId int not null

---

I want to extract the following data from these tables where the RegName is equal to the Regname in the TextField RegName

FROM doginfo DogId, RegNum, RegName, WhelpDate, DNA, Notes, From dogat Breed, Sex, color, 
FROM sires SireRegname, FROM dams DamRegName, FROM owners LastName, Address1, address2, City, State, Zip, HTel, Cell, FROM coowners Coownernames

Once I get the data I want to insert it into the matching TextField.

Here is my code when I run it myRs is always empty and I get an exception error.

```
  // Query the db for record with dog name equal to the name in regName.
    String user = "root";
      String password = "";
      String dn = null;
      String ResultSet = null; // This is to ensure that ResultSet is empty.


      dn = RegName.getText().trim();  // dn = dog name from RegName TextField.
      //System.out.println (dn);
    try {

        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kennelmanagment1", user, password);
            System.out.println("Connection Successful ");
        // Create statement.
         Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

        // Execute query.
       //This seems to be were my problems occur !!!!!!!!!!

       ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT d.DogId, d.RegNum, d.RegName, d.WhelpDate, d.DNA, d.Notes, a.Breed, a.Sex, a.color, s.SireRegName, b.DamRegName, o.LastName, c.CoOwnerNames, o.Address1, o.Address2, o.City, o.State, o.Zip, o.Htel, o.Cell \n"
                + "FROM doginfo d "
               + "LEFT JOIN dogat a \n"
                + "ON d.DogId = a.DogId\n"
                + "LEFT JOIN sires s\n"
                + "ON d.DogId = s.DogId\n"
                + "LEFT JOIN dams b\n"
                + "ON d.DogId = b.DogId\n"
                + "LEFT JOIN owners o\n"
                + "ON d.DogId = o.DogId\n"
                + "LEFT JOIN coowners c\n"
                + "ON d.DogId = c.DogId"
                +" WHERE d.RegName =    '"+dn+ "'  " );

    //ResultSet myRS = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT doginfo.DogId FROM doginfo where doginfo.regname = 'dn');");
     System.out.println(myStmt);
     System.out.println(ResultSet);
      System.out.println(myRs);
```

//public void run() {

// }
//};

```
     System.out.println (dn);
        //System.out.println ("####SELECT * FROM doginfo WHERE Regname = '" + dn + " '  ");
        System.out.println(" ****"+dn +"**");
       // System.out.println (size);
       // Process the result.
        while (myRs.next ()) {
            //System.out.println(myRs.getInt("DogId"));
             DogId.setText(myRs.getString("DogId"));
             RegNum.setText (myRs.getString ("RegNum"));
             RegName.setText(myRs.getString ("RegName"));
             WhelpDate.setText (myRs.getString("WhelpDate"));
             Breed.setText (myRs.getString ("breed"));
             Sex.setText (myRs.getString ("sex"));
             Color.setText (myRs.getString ("color"));
             SireRegName.setText (myRs.getString ("SireRegName"));
             DamRegName.setText (myRs.getString ("DamRegNName"));
             LastName.setText (myRs.getString ("LastName"));
             CoOwnerNames.setText (myRs.getString("CoOwnerNmae"));
             Address1.setText (myRs.getString ("Address1"));
             Address2.setText (myRs.getString ("Addess2"));
             City.setText (myRs.getString("City"));
             State.setText (myRs.getString ("State"));
             Zip.setText (myRs.getString ("Zip"));
             DNA.setText (myRs.getString ("DNA"));
             HTel.setText (myRs.getString ("HTel"));
             Cell.setText (myRs.getString ("Cell"));
             Notes.setText (myRs.getString ("Notes"));

     }

        }  catch (Exception  e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Error");
      }    



}
```

Comment: What is the exception thrown? 
What does the query return when you run it on an sql client?

Comment: If I run it without the where d.Regname = ' " + dn + ' " I get information on one dog but it is always the same dog and not the one I am looking for also I only get data up to sire the rest is missing. I am haveing trouble getting the where to work. I have tried everything I can think of to no avail. Let me know if you need more informantion.

Comment: You didn't answer BudsNanKis's questions.  If you run the query directly in an sql client, what is the result?  What are the exception messages?  More information is needed to help you.

Comment: add `e.printStackTrace();` in the catch clause so you can see WHAT the Exception is! Just "Error" is not very helpful...

Comment: and I would try to not use the `doginfo` table in all `on` conditions, that is, only the last two tables - the one just before and the one just after the corresponding JOIN. `... LEFT JOIN dogat a ON d.DogId = a.DogId LEFT JOIN sires s ON a.DogId = s.DogId ...`

Comment: I can't run the query directly because it gets information (ie. RegName) from the java app. however if I run in directly without the where I get the information I am looking for. with the where it seems that the ResultSet or myStmt is empty, but with out the where it returns part of the data after giving me an xception error message from the java app catch line above.

Comment: The trace was a big help it helped me fix several type o's in my (while (myRs.next()) ) statement so that now I fill out the whole form however, I still get the same dog which is the last dog in the table. I somehow need to get the part that says I want the dog who's name matches the dog who's name is in the TextField RegName to work I am using an INNER JOIN  in the select statement instead of the LEFT JOIN. Haven't yet tried it after adding the WHERE d.RegName = ' " +dn+ " ' ");. Will report here after trying.

Comment: Nope when I add the WHERE I get nothing. Nothing changes and I don't get any exception error.